# boost:asio HTTP server example 3 thread count (Windows build)

Tags: multithreading, http, boost, boost-asio

In example 3 of the HTTP server (boost 2.44), the IO service is created without a thread count hint. Under Windows, one normally passes the thread count to CreateIoCompletionPort(). boost:asio has an IO Service ctor that takes the thread count, but that ctor is not used in this example. And the thread count is known.

My question is: is there a reason to create the IO Service without the thread count? Does boost:asio assume one would never create more threads than one per core? Note if the thread count passed to CreateIoCompletionPort() is zero, the system will allow one thread per core concurrently running threads.

Comment: Someone change the title. "boost::asio::io_service() concurrency_hint question Windows" Would make a great title. So others can google easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the parameter-less constructor on `io_service`, the call to `CreateIoCompletionPort` winds up using a thread count of 0xffffffff in the code here:

```
void win_iocp_io_service::init(size_t concurrency_hint)
{
  iocp_.handle = ::CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 0,
      static_cast<DWORD>((std::min<size_t>)(concurrency_hint, DWORD(~0))));
  if (!iocp_.handle)
  {
    DWORD last_error = ::GetLastError();
    boost::system::error_code ec(last_error,
        boost::asio::error::get_system_category());
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "iocp");
  }
}
```

Not sure how Windows interprets this but the call works OK, so I assume this is the same as using 0.  I guess the assumption is that the OS knows best?

Comment: Zero means the OS allows at most core-count threads to run concurrently. That's fine, but some people like to allow for two threads per core by default. To me, it would make more sense to use the thread count, which is known.

Comment: Yes, the solution would be to use a different constructor.  Probably just keeping the example code simple.

Comment: That's probably it. I wish they would say so.

Comment: Boost example code can be a bit sketchy.  In this case I am grateful there are several ASIO examples, it's not an easy library to get used to.

Comment: In the examples, it appears a lot is done for expediency and not really applicable to what one would do in the real world. But this seems to be a problem with example code in general. In the end, the source code tells the real story and this is what we ultimately have to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

When `concurrency_hint` is not specified to `boost:asio::io_service()` constructor. Default is **infinite** or **unbounded**, which is never the best practice. But the designer probably felt this Windows based concurrency_hint was unnecessary, so made the default consistent with all platforms (no limit). This is likely to be consistent with how other OS interpret this value.

Since Windows itself creates no threads out of this whole fiasco, it shouldn't even care. `concurrency_hint` should be renamed `max_allowed_concurrency_on_Windows`